# Forge viewer - Download pdf derivative via API

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api

Can I download a pdf from a derivative via API?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what exactly you're asking for. Below are a couple of answers to what I think your question could be:

#### You have uploaded a PDF file to the Model Derivative service, and you would like to download the results of the conversion?

While you *can* download the derivatives of 3D models, I'm afraid it is not possible for PDFs. When processing PDFs, the Model Derivative service converts them to [image pyramids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing)) to enable Google Maps-like experience where zooming in on different parts of the PDF will load in higher resolution images of the area.

However, if your goal is to be able to load a PDF into the viewer *without* the Model Derivative service, note that this is also possible: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/dwf-and-pdf-support-forge-viewer

#### You have uploaded a design (e.g., a Revit design) to the Model Derivative service, and you would like to download the PDF output that the service generated?

If you're interested in converting Revit designs to PDFs, I would suggest that you generate the PDFs using the [Design Automation for Revit](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/) as this service is better suited for these types of tasks.